How to check if a SCNNode's geometry is visible and not obstructed by other nodes in SceneKit?
I have a container with many toy nodes. I want to touch the screen to pick up all the visible nodes.
I did a hit test to get the list of all nodes in my touch location. However, some of the nodes are not actually visible - they are obstructed by other nodes.
How can I check if the node is "visible" to the screen, without being blocked by others?
